# Could someone explain this proof to me? Probability proof

Tags: probability

> If event $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are either $0$ or $1$ and $A$ is subset of $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are dependent events.
>
> Proof: Since $A\subset B$, we have $A\cap B=A$ and so $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$.
>
> $\therefore$ $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)[1-P(B)]$
> Since $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)<1$,

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXWyF.jpg))

Where did that last step come from, involving $P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B)$? How did the solution come up with that?

Comment: There is only one step. The point is showing that $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A) P(B)$, i.e. that $P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B) \neq 0$. The steps to $P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B) = P(A) (1 - P(B))$ are well explained in your writing, but if $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 1$, your events are indeed independent (you will get $0$). So perhaps the theorem you need to assume you don't have such cases happening. If that is of any help... ( I must say it doesn't look quite clear what you assume and what you don't on the values of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.)

Comment: So it's proving by contradiction essentially?

Comment: @jak: No,  the statement you are trying to prove is just wrong.  If $P(A) = 0$ or $P(A) = 1$, then $A$ is independent of every event, including itself.  Perhaps the "either ... or" was supposed to be "neither ... nor".

Comment: One common strategy for showing that $x\ne y$ is to show that $x-y\ne 0$. In this case, it is not really of great help, since from $P(A)=P(A)P(B)$, we can, assuming that $P(A)\ne 0$, cancel and deduce that $P(B)=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result has clearly been misstated or miscopied. The proof is correct for the following result:

> If event $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are **neither** $0$ **nor** $1$, and $A$ is subset of $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are dependent events.

The reason for looking at $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)$ is that by definition, $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, i.e., if and only if $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=0$. But the hypothesis that $A\subseteq B$ implies that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)$, so $$P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)\big(1-P(B)\big)\;,$$

which is $0$ if and only if either $P(A)=0$ or $1-P(B)=0$, i.e., if and only if either $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=1$. These possibilities are ruled out by the corrected version of the hypothesis, so it must be the case that $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\ne 0$, $P(A\cap B)\ne P(A)P(B)$, and hence by definition $A$ and $B$ are **not** independent (which of course means that they are dependent).

The answer by copper.hat shows why the stated version is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are only three possibilities to consider:

$$\begin{matrix}
PA & PB & P (A \cap B) & PA.PB \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}$$

In all cases $PA.PB = P(A \cap B)$, so the events are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's something wrong with the initial statement to me.
If $ A = \emptyset \subset B $ then $P(A \cap B)=P(\emptyset \cap B)=P(\emptyset)=0=P(\emptyset)P(B)=P(A)P(B)$.